# 5x5 Grid in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, grid

developers, I want to make a 5x5 grid in python I try this code but I fail to generate my required output here I use abc for while loop

```
    l1 = []
    abc = 1
    while abc == 5:
       for i in range(1,6,1):
          l1.append(i)
           abc+=1
     print(l1)
```

but its out was only []

I want this type of output

```
['0','0','0','0','0']

['0','0','0','0','0']

['0','0','0','0','0']

['0','0','0','0','0']

['0','0','0','0','0']
```

Comment: do you want a list of 5 lists with 5 elements which are all 0?

Comment: No, it depends I just write the example output

Comment: `abc` never equals 5, you set it equal to `1` and therefore don't enter the `while` loop. If you did enter the loop, you'd then be appending the results of `range` so wouldn't get all zeros, and your example output also seems to want strings. Please clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: your loop will only be executed when abc=5, and the value of abc will always be 1, that's why the output is []

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is quite confusing since you have a conditional `abc == 5` in your while loop, so it will never execute. You can generate what you want by:

```
[[i for i in range(j, j + 5)] for j in range(0, 25, 5)]
```

so the output will be:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

in case you want it to start at 1 and finish at 25:

```
[[i for i in range(j, j + 5)] for j in range(1, 26, 5)]
```

so the output will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
 [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

**Update: (based on the output you provided in the question)**:

```
grid = [[i for i in range(j, j + 5)] for j in range(0, 25, 5)]
for item in grid:
    print(item)
```

Comment: it generates the output in the same line like
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]

but I need the output in separate line

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess as to what I believe you are asking:

```
>>> l1 = [[i for i in range(1, 6)] for _ in range(5)]
>>> print(*l1, sep='\n')
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

This `print()` idiom is simple enough to memorize and use whenever you're in the Python shell and want to quickly examine a two dimensional list.